# Rest api to get product by sku with custom attribute option value in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api

I am using `Magento 2.1.6 CE` and also am using default `rest api's` for create mobile app. When I get `product by sku` I get all the details of the particular product including custom attributes also.

But in custom attributes I have some attributes like `color` attribute (i.e. dropdown and filterable). I have various options for `color` attribute like `Blue, Green, Red` etc

When am requesting `/V1/products/{{sku}}` it shows custom attributes like following, (it shows `option_id` instead of `option_value`).

```
....
{
   "attribute_code": "color",
   "value": "11"
},
....
```

But I need this like the following,

```
....
{
   "attribute_code": "color",
   "value": "Green"
},
....
```

How can I get this done?

Please suggest me is there any default options available to done this.

Comment: hi @vignesh please confirm those attributes  showing on product view page at moe information section?

Comment: Yes it's showing there correctly @NagarajuKasa

Comment: whether you would like to implement new api from your custom module? ex:- rest/V1/product/sku

Comment: No am using default one only @NagarajuKasa

Comment: hi @vignesh bala please check my answer  and get back with u r doubts so that i will assist u thanks

Comment: hi @vignesh bala have u tried the below answer ?

Comment: It's not working @NagarajuKasa I am not get any attribute code like "more_information"

Comment: actually u have to create a more_information attribute at admin end. then set the custom data (array) to that attribute

Comment: go to admin and create a product attribute called  more_information

Comment: @VigneshBala Have you worked any solution I have need same color attribute selected option label in product rest API.

Comment: @KirtiNariya The answer works fine. Please try with same. contact me at vigneshbala793 @ gmail . com

Comment: @VigneshBala I have tried same for color attribute selected option label but can't get for same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please follow the below steps from custom module if it success then you can customize whatever you want.

**Note:-** we are creating a new product attribute and associating the required data to the product attribute.

Step 1:- create a new module using silk software tool ex:- **CompanyName_ModuleName**

Step 2:- create a new product attribute using install script (or) admin end.

Step 3:- create a webapi.xml => /app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
<route url="/V1/product/:sku" method="GET">
        <service class="CompanyName\ModuleName\Api\ProductsInterface" method="getAdditional"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Step 4: app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="CompanyName\ModuleName\Api\ProductsInterface" type="CompanyName\ModuleName\Model\Products" />  
</config>
```

Step 5: app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/Api/ProductsInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Api;

interface ProductsInterface
{
     /**
     * Get info about product by product SKU
     *
     * @param string $sku
     * @param bool $editMode
     * @param int|null $storeId
     * @param bool $forceReload
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getAdditional($sku, $editMode = false, $storeId = null, $forceReload = false);

}
```

Step 6: app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/Model/Products.php

```
 <?php
namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;

class Products implements \Ewall\Mobileshop\Api\ProductsInterface
{
   /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $productFactory;

    /**
     * @var Product[]
     */
    protected $instances = [];

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product
     */
    protected $resourceModel;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory
     */
    protected $helperFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation
     */
    protected $appEmulation;

    /**
     * Review model
     *
     * @var \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory
     */
    protected $_reviewFactory;

     /**
     * Review resource model
     *
     * @var \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_reviewsColFactory;

    /**
     * @var PriceCurrencyInterface
     */
    protected $priceCurrency;

    /**
     * ProductRepository constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $resourceModel
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param  \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory
     * @param  \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $resourceModel,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $appEmulation,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $helperFactory,
        \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory,
        \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
    ) {
        $this->productFactory       =  $productFactory;
        $this->storeManager         =  $storeManager;
        $this->resourceModel        =  $resourceModel;
        $this->helperFactory        =  $helperFactory;
        $this->appEmulation         =  $appEmulation;
        $this->_reviewFactory       =  $reviewFactory;
        $this->_reviewsColFactory   =  $collectionFactory;
        $this->priceCurrency        =  $priceCurrency;

    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAdditional($sku, $editMode = false, $storeId = null, $forceReload = false)
    {
        $cacheKey = $this->getCacheKey([$editMode, $storeId]);
        if (!isset($this->instances[$sku][$cacheKey]) || $forceReload) {
            $product = $this->productFactory->create();

            $productId = $this->resourceModel->getIdBySku($sku);

            if (!$productId) {

                throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Requested product doesn\'t exist'));
            }
            if ($editMode) {
                $product->setData('_edit_mode', true);
            }
            if ($storeId !== null) {
                $product->setData('store_id', $storeId);
            } else {

                $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            }
            $product->load($productId);

            //Custom Attributes Data Added here            
            $moreInformation = $this->getMoreInformation($product);                     
            $product->setCustomAttribute('more_information', $moreInformation);
            // Custom Attributes Data Ends here
            $this->instances[$sku][$cacheKey] = $product;
            $this->instancesById[$product->getId()][$cacheKey] = $product;          
        }

        return $this->instancesById[$product->getId()][$cacheKey];      

   }


    /**
     * Get key for cache
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return string
     */

    protected function getCacheKey($data)
    {
        $serializeData = [];
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {         

            if (is_object($value)) {
                $serializeData[$key] = $value->getId();             
            } else {                
                $serializeData[$key] = $value;              
            }
        }       
        return md5(serialize($serializeData));
    }




    /**
     * Get More information of the product
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @return array
    */

    protected function getMoreInformation($product)
    {
        $data = [];
        $excludeAttr = [];
        $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && !in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $excludeAttr)) {
                $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

                if (!$product->hasData($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {
                    $value = __('N/A');
                } elseif ((string)$value == '') {
                    $value = __('No');
                } elseif ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'price' && is_string($value)) {
                    $value = $this->priceCurrency->convertAndFormat($value);
                }

                if (is_string($value) && strlen($value)) {
                    $data[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = [
                        'label' => __($attribute->getStoreLabel()),
                        'value' => $value,
                        'code' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }



}
```

Step 7: after did the changes make sure use **di:compile**

Step 8: open postman application for getting the result as shown below

Method: GET

UrL:- http://website.com/rest/V1/product/24-MB04

Step 9: Output
[image]

Comment: Okay I will check this one and let you know ASAP. Thanks ...

Comment: thanks vignesh here i am customizing the entire api  functionality from the custom module please get back with ur comments.

Comment: In your screen shot Activity attribute has 4 values, If am selected Gym only for product 24-MB04. How can I get that only ?

Comment: you will get like this https://prnt.sc/geumys

Comment: So Activity is multiselect attribute. right ?

Comment: yes@vignesh exactly let's try http://prntscr.com/geus74

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64812/discussion-between-vignesh-bala-and-nagaraju-kasa).

Comment: you are welcome @AdityaShah

Comment: @NagarajuKasa I have need same Selected attributes option label in Product API. I have follow your steps but can't get any results.

Comment: @NagarajuK This is isn't working in magento2.3.4 , if you have solution please share with us

Comment: I have created integration in admin section,tried create a product post method payload with Consumer Key,Consumer Secret,Access Token,Access Token Secret but getting " The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources "

Answer (score 1):

In lastest Magento 2 Versions Try this

```
/rest/V1/products/:sku
```